# Microservices - RestTemplate UnknownHostException

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud, microservices, netflix-eureka

I have a simple setup with a Eureka service registration server, a service for the public API and a service that gets called from the public API using RestTemplate. Eureka tells me that the services are successfully registered, but when I call the service

```
@Service
public class MyServiceService {

    @Autowired
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    private final String serviceUrl;

    public MyServiceService() {
        this.serviceUrl = "http://MY-SERVICE";
    }

    public Map<String, String> getTest() {

        Map<String, String> vars = new HashMap<>();
        vars.put("id", "1");

        restTemplate.setRequestFactory(new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory());

        return restTemplate.postForObject(serviceUrl+"/test", "", Map.class, vars);
    }
}
```

I get the following exception

```
Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed;
  nested exception is org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on POST request for "http://MY-SERVICE/test": MY-SERVICE;
  nested exception is java.net.UnknownHostException: MY-SERVICE] with root cause java.net.UnknownHostException: MY-SERVICE
```

I created a sample project to illustrate my setup, maybe someone could take a look at it and tell me what's wrong with my setup.

https://github.com/KenavR/spring-boot-microservices-example

thanks

Comment: It appears as though the `RestTemplate` being injected isn't the load balanced one.  Since you're using Spring Cloud Angel.SR6 in your project, it should inject the load balanced one automatically.  The only suggestion I can think of is to annotate your `RestTemplate` with `@LoadBalanced` and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: I tried that in the past and now again, sadly the error stays the same.

Comment: Have you tried Spring Cloud Brixton.RELEASE, it was released today.  Just note that with Brixton, you have to define your own `@LoadBalanced @Bean RestTemplate` because Brixton no longer creates one by default.  Then you can `@Autowire` it as usual.  Barring that, you could try calling your service with the service ID in lower case `http://my-service/test`.

Comment: Switching to Brixton and changing the code were needed fixed the issue, thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As suggested by [patrick-grimard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/672859/patrick-grimard) switching to Brixton and changing the code were needed fixed the issues. Working Solution is on [Github](https://github.com/KenavR/spring-boot-microservices-example).

Also changed the posted `id` from request param to request body, which also changed the way I add it to the request.

**Service endpoint**

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json; charset=utf-8")
public @ResponseBody Map<String, String> getTest(@RequestBody Map<String, Long> params) {

    Map<String, String> response = new HashMap<>();

    response.put("name", "My Service");

    return response;
}
```

**RestTemplate creation**

```
@Configuration
public class PublicAPIConfiguration {
    @LoadBalanced
    @Bean
    RestTemplate restTemplate() {
        return new RestTemplate();
    }
}
```

**Calling service**

```
@Service
public class MyServiceService {

    @Autowired
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    private final String serviceUrl;

    public MyServiceService() {
        this.serviceUrl = "http://my-service";
    }

    public Map<String, String> getTest() {

        Map<String, Long> vars = new HashMap<>();
        vars.put("id", 1L);

        return restTemplate.postForObject(serviceUrl+"/test", vars, Map.class);
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you be more specific? Was the related to Spring version?

Comment: I have similar issue. My service have been using RestTemplate to talk to another service with http://myhost.com. Although, we didn't change anything it began throwing UnknownHostException.
ping myhost.com is ok.

Answer (score 1):

Just for anyone in the future that might also happen to come across this issue, i had the exact same stacktrace, but was slightly different for a solution.

My issue was not related to a configuration from a coding standpoint. It was related to the server i was running the code on. I was ignoring the fact that it was on a DMZ, which doesn't have a DNS, so you have to manually map a domain to an IP.

More or less, make sure your DNS is properly configured on your server, because, from a restTemplate standpoint, it will throw this exact stacktrace.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the `@LoadBalanced` to `RestTemplate` bean creation  worked for me